# How can I get rid of just the untracked files in git?

Tags: git, mercurial

In Mercurial I can do this with the bundled [Purge Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PurgeExtension) and executing the following command:

```
hg purge
```

Also good to get rid of ignored files:

```
hg purge --all
```

I'm curious about the most practical/used equivalent solution in git.

**Edit**: I want to just get rid of the untracked files, not reset everything (e.g. suppose I have a program generating cache files or generated code and I want to delete them with git's help)

Comment: This question is off-topic on Programmers and would be a duplicate on Stack Overflow, where it should have been asked, see [Removing untracked files from your git working copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/removing-untracked-files-from-your-git-working-copy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's git reset with the option --hard:

```
git reset --hard
```

Here is an SO answer which have more details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9530204/70386

And the manual:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html

**Edit**

To only delete untracked files, use `clean`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/removing-untracked-files-from-your-git-working-copy

Manual entry:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clean.html

Comment: Sorry, made my question a little more specific, I meant **only** the untracked files

Comment: I've added git clean.

Answer (score 7):

For all `git clean` commands, add `-n` for dry-run.

Clean all untracked files and directories, except ignored files (listed in .gitignore):

```
git clean -fd
```

Also clean ignored files:

```
git clean -fdx
```

**Only** clean ignored files (useful for removing build artifacts, to ensure a fresh build from scratch, without discarding new files/directories you haven't committed yet):

```
git clean -fdX
```